# (-) sign in y ticks label are not written in Seaborn

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I'm studying Seaborn package and I encountered strange problem.

There is (-) sign in the y tick labels of the original figure. The original figure is from seaborn web page.

```
sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="sex", data=tips, split=True);
```

[https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/_images/categorical_23_0.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvvjK.png)

However, when I draw this plot with the same code, (-) sign in the y tick labels doesn't have (-).

```
sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="sex", data=tips, split=True);
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RcbL.png]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you referring to the "negative sign"?  Can you show us an unabridged example (code and/or image)?

Comment: Yes, negative sign. And I added the link!

Comment: What version of python, Seaborn, and matplotlib are you using? When I use the code you list, the negative mark (-) is shown correctly.

Comment: I'm using - python: 3.4.3, seaborn: 0.6.0, matplotlib: 1.4.3.

Comment: Can you update matplotlib to 1.5?

Comment: I updated it, but the problem was still the same. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all!

I probably found out the reason.
The default font doesn't seem to provide (-) sign properly.

When I changed it to 'Helvetica', it works well.
Thank you for helping me! :D

Comment: An actual bug. 2019, python 3.6, latest pip version of matplotlib. Still a thing.